# Can't apply styles to div

Tags: css, html

So basically, I can't apply styles from the .hl class to the div at the bottom.  I was able to force the class to work by removing all of the other css at the top of the code.  Any ideas what's conflicting with the .hl class and how to fix it?

Thanks for any help.  Also, I am aware that there aren't html tags around the body of the code.  This code is set to run inside of the Spiceworks user portal, so in order to provide styles for separate content blocks, they have to be inside a p tag.

Thanks again!

```
<p>
    <style type="text/css">
    table
    {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    h2, h3
    {
        font-family: calibri;
    }
    p.lynx
    {
        font-family: calibri;
        font-size: 11pt;
    }
    a:link
    {
        color: #000000;
    }
    a:visited
    {
        color: #000000;
    }
    a:hover
    {
        color: #666666;
    }
    a.bottomanchor
    {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a.bottomanchor:hover
    {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a.bottomnotice
    {
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a.bottomnotice:hover
    {
        text-decoration: none;
    p.asterisk
    {
        font-family: calibri;
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
    p.title
    {
        font-family: calibri;
        font-size: 36pt;
    }
    .hl
    {
        border:  2px solid #000000;
        padding:  10px 40px; 
        background:  #dddddd;
        width:  750px;
        border-radius:  25px;
        align: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
</p>

<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>

<p align="center" class="title"><u><strong>PRINTABLE FORMS</strong></u></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<h2 align="center">Click a title to open a printable version of the document in a new tab.<a class="bottomanchor" href="#astrsk">*</a></h2>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div>
    <table align="center" height="100%" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr align="center" height="250px" width="100%">
        <td align="center" width="25%"><img alt="" src="http://i1099.photobucket.com/albums/g383/zachoxley/MarksNelson/MNVCR%20Forms/401kiconsmall_zpsd588e17a.png" style="border-style: none" /></td>
        <td align="center" width="25%"><img alt="" src="http://i1099.photobucket.com/albums/g383/zachoxley/MarksNelson/MNVCR%20Forms/Vacationiconsmall_zps76461606.png" style="border-style: none" /></td>
        <td align="center" width="25%"><img alt="" src="http://i1099.photobucket.com/albums/g383/zachoxley/MarksNelson/MNVCR%20Forms/TAXRETURNCONTROLSHEETiconsmall_zps9cee6b93.png" style="opacity: 0.9; text-align: -webkit-center; border-style: none;" /></td>
        <td align="center" width="25%"><img alt="" src="http://i1099.photobucket.com/albums/g383/zachoxley/MarksNelson/MNVCR%20Forms/CPERequestForm-Revised2013iconsmall_zpse35da75b.png" style="border-style: none" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="50px" width="100%">
        <td align="center" width="25%">
        <p class="lynx"><a href="file:///\\mnvcrdata\Data\Firm Administration\IT Department\IT Portal HR Documents\MNVCR 401(k).pdf" target="_blank">MNVCR 401(k) Plan</a></p>
        </td>
        <td align="center" width="25%">
        <p class="lynx"><a href="file:///\\mnvcrdata\Data\Firm Administration\IT Department\IT Portal HR Documents\Vacation request.pdf" target="_blank">Vacation Request</a></p>
        </td>
        <td align="center" width="25%">
        <p class="lynx"><a href="file:///\\mnvcrdata\Data\Firm Administration\IT Department\IT Portal HR Documents\TAX RETURN CONTROL SHEET.pdf" target="_blank">Tax Return Control Sheet</a></p>
        </td>
        <td align="center" width="25%">
        <p class="lynx"><a href="file:///\\mnvcrdata\Data\Firm Administration\IT Department\IT Portal HR Documents\CPE Request Form - Revised 2013.pdf" target="_blank">CPE Request Form</a></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" height="20px">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center" height="250px" width="100%">
        <td align="center" width="25%"><img alt="" src="http://i1099.photobucket.com/albums/g383/zachoxley/MarksNelson/MNVCR%20Forms/FaxCoverSheeticonsmall_zps2bc8e77f.png" style="border-style: none" /></td>
        <td align="center" width="25%"><img alt="" src="http://i1099.photobucket.com/albums/g383/zachoxley/MarksNelson/MNVCR%20Forms/ProspectiveClientQuestionsFormBiconsmall_zps61cf954a.png" style="border-style: none" /></td>
        <td align="center" width="25%"><img alt="" src="http://i1099.photobucket.com/albums/g383/zachoxley/MarksNelson/MNVCR%20Forms/FormB1iconsmall_zps285b1414.png" style="border-style: none" /></td>
        <td align="center" width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="50px" width="100%">
        <td align="center" width="25%">
        <p class="lynx"><a href="file:///\\mnvcrdata\Data\Firm Administration\IT Department\IT Portal HR Documents\Fax Cover Sheet Template.doc" target="_blank">Fax Cover Sheet</a></p>
        </td>
        <td align="center" width="25%">
        <p class="lynx"><a href="file:///\\mnvcrdata\Data\Firm Administration\IT Department\IT Portal HR Documents\FORM B - Prospective Client Questions.pdf" target="_blank">Prospective Client Questions (B)</a></p>
        </td>
        <td align="center" width="25%">
        <p class="lynx"><a href="file:///\\mnvcrdata\Data\Firm Administration\IT Department\IT Portal HR Documents\FORM B1 - Prospective Client Approval Form.pdf" target="_blank">Prospective Client Form (B1)</a></p>
        </td>
        <td align="center" width="25%">
        <p class="lynx">&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
        <hr width="100%" /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="hl">
<strong><a class="bottomnotice" name="astrsk">* - Not supported on Mozilla Firefox. Use Internet Explorer or Google Chrome for this feature.</a></strong><br />
<strong>For Chrome users:  </strong><a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida" target="_blank">LocalLinks Extension</a>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a closing `}` after `a.bottomnotice:hover`.

Comment: ::shamefaced::  Sometimes you just need a good pair of eyes to fix the problems.  Haha.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, it happens to everyone :)